# Unable to start msfconsole or msfdb due to LoadError and ThreadError

Tags: ruby, metasploit

I am trying to run msfdb but I can't seem to do so because I get a LoadError and 2 ThreadErrors. Here is the full stack:

```
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require': cannot load such file -- net/smtp (LoadError)
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/rex/proto/sms/model.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `require'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:27:in `require'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `const_get'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in `cget'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:26:in `block in ls'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `each_child'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:18:in `ls'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:232:in `block in eager_load'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:217:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:217:in `eager_load'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:317:in `each'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:317:in `eager_load_all'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:133:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/johnmap007/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `public_send'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msfenv.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/lib/msfenv.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/msfconsole:18:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/msfconsole:18:in `<main>'
/usr/bin/msfconsole: warning: Exception in finalizer #<Proc:0x00007f4a9fb4fc80 /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/atomic/ruby_thread_local_var.rb:85>
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/logging-2.3.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471:in `new': can't alloc thread (ThreadError)
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/logging-2.3.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471:in `create_with_logging_context'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/logging-2.3.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:436:in `new'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/atomic/ruby_thread_local_var.rb:86:in `block in threadlocal_finalizer'
/usr/bin/msfconsole: warning: Exception in finalizer #<Proc:0x00007f4a9fb4fde8 /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/atomic/ruby_thread_local_var.rb:85>
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/logging-2.3.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471:in `new': can't alloc thread (ThreadError)
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/logging-2.3.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:471:in `create_with_logging_context'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/logging-2.3.0/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:436:in `new'
        from /usr/share/metasploit-framework/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/atomic/ruby_thread_local_var.rb:86:in `block in threadlocal_finalizer'
```

Side Note: From what I understand, the 2 ThreadErrors that were thrown were because I have insufficient memory? I have 16GB total though, that should be enough.

Before this, I was unable to install certain dependencies because of some weird reason but I installed Oracle Instant Client, which allowed me to install `ruby-oci8`, which then let me continue with the rest of the dependency installation. I reran `bundle install` for that and that fixed most of it (I had to manually install certain gems with `gem install <gem>` but reran `bundle install` to make sure I had everything at the end). Now I'm getting these weird LoadErrors and ThreadErrors. One thing to note is that I'm executing `msfdb run` and `msfconsole` **as root** (It's necessary for `msfdb run` because it won't let me run it as a normal user), but when I run msfconsole as a normal user, metasploit loads as expected without any errors. Can someone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ruby 3.1, [`net-smtp` is a bundled gem](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1fd1f7bbfc5603cdcfa98363a9ec9e106705a0a3/doc/NEWS/NEWS-3.1.0.md?plain=1#L389).

Probably, you just need to add

```rb
gem 'net-smtp'
```

to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Is there a specific place I should put it in or just anywhere in the Gemfile?

Comment: Just throw it anywhere at the top-level (not within a group).